# Is the bottleneck shortest path a collection of shortest edges or longest edges from s to t?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I just found about about the *bottleneck shortest path* problem, and I'm really confused about what we need to find there. Do we need to find the maximum cost edge on the path from s to t consisting of short edges, or the minimum cost edge on the path consisting of the long edges? The latter makes more sense to me, and it's described under the picture at right on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem

But when I looked at this link : http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~anderson/iucee/Slides_421_06/Lecture08_09_10.pdf

the algorithm described there doesn't seem to find the path consisting of long edges, I even implemented it and tested it on this graph: [image]

Here's the algorithm that I took from that link above:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;


public class BSP {
    private double[] d;
    private DirectedWeightedEdge[] edgeTo;
    private PriorityQueue<Integer> pq;
    private boolean[] visited;

    private class VertexComparer implements Comparator<Integer> {
        public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
            if (d[one] < d[two]) return -1;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public BSP(WeightedDigraph G, int source) {
        d = new double[G.V()];
        edgeTo = new DirectedWeightedEdge[G.V()];
        visited = new boolean[G.V()];
        for (int i = 0; i < G.V(); ++i) d[i] = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        d[source] = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new VertexComparer());
        pq.add(source);
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            int top = pq.poll();
            if (!visited[top])
                relax(G, top);
        }
    }    

    private void relax(WeightedDigraph G, int v) {
        visited[v] = true;
        for (DirectedWeightedEdge e : G.adj(v)) {
            if (d[e.to()] > Math.max(d[e.from()], e.weight())) {
                d[e.to()] = Math.max(d[e.from()], e.weight());
                edgeTo[e.to()] = e;
                pq.add(e.to());
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hasPathTo(int v) {
        return edgeTo[v] != null;
    }

    public Iterable<Integer> pathTo(int v) {
        assert hasPathTo(v);
        int w = v;
        DirectedWeightedEdge e = edgeTo[w];
        Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for (; edgeTo[w] != null; e = edgeTo[e.from()]) {
            stack.push(w);
            w = e.from();
        }
        stack.push(w);
        return stack;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't that algorithm also find the path consisting of long edges, from 0 to 3, for example : {0,4}, {4,3} and conclude that the answer is 4? I can't seem to understand why it finds the path 0->1->2->3 instead. Or is the problem somehow different for directed graphs?

If the algorithm described on that link is wrong, please let me know what the right algorithm is. I just can't seem to understand why 2 sources give different information.

Comment: How did you understand anything from that PDF? It seems like a teaching aid / presentation material, not a complete, structured paper. Anyway, the widest path deals with bandwidth (or weight), not with distance / length, and look to find a path where the minimum bandwidth included in the path is maximized - in other words - that no other path exist such that it's minimum bandwidth is higher.

Comment: @Amit if you read the pseudocode more carefully it does exactly what I wrote in java, also I don't store distances anywhere, I only store lengths of edges. I was confused, because wikipedia says what you just said, but that algorithm does the opposite. In this case, how to I use Dijkstra to find the BSP?

Comment: @Amit  also that pdf gives the following definition: Define the bottleneck distance for a path to be the maximum cost edge along the path, which is the opposite of what you said as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many similar problems, the bottleneck problem is symmetrical. In fact, you can talk of *two* different problems:

- Find a path that has its *shortest* edge *as long* as possible
- Find a path that has its *longest* edge *as short* as possible

The algorithm for both versions is the same, except that you reverse all weight relations (change max-heap to min-heap or vice-versa, change the sign of comparison in `relax()`, etc.) Even [the Wikipedia link you gave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem) states:

> A closely related problem, the minimax path problem, asks for the path
>   that minimizes the maximum weight of any of its edges. <...> Any algorithm
>   for the widest path problem can be transformed into an algorithm for
>   the minimax path problem, or vice versa, by reversing the sense of all
>   the weight comparisons performed by the algorithm, or equivalently by
>   replacing every edge weight by its negation.

Obviously, both versions can be called the bottleneck problem, and you just came across lecture notes that talks about the second version. As the algorithms are the same, no much confusion will arise, you just need to be explicit about what version do you talk about.